# get the source of web in as3

Tags: html, actionscript-3, httpwebrequest, urlloader

This is probably an imposible thing to do, but I want to ask.
Is there a way to get the html source of a webpage by providing a link?

Comment: You could have at least accepted my answer if it helped you. Or let me know if it didn't.

Answer (score 9):

Of course there is. I don't see why you got so many negative votes. Anyway, here's a snippet for you:

```
var pageLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(); //make a loader that will load a page
var pageRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://google.com"); //make a request with a url to page
pageRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.GET; //set request's html request method to GET

pageLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onPageLoaded); //listen for page load
pageLoader.load(pageRequest); //actually load the page

function onPageLoaded(e:Event):void
{
    trace(pageLoader.data); //handle the data from the loader
}
```

You can also get a reference to your `pageLoader` instance from your handler function using the `e.target`. Good luck.